# Limiting peak current draw with a supercapacitor or battery

Tags: power-supply, supercapacitor, poe

I'm working on a project that runs on 12V DC. The power comes via PoE, which induces a hard limit of 15 watts on the design.

The circuit is intended to drive multiple loads that are rated for ~7W each, but only sporadically and only a few seconds at a time. However, it's likely that multiple loads activate simultaneously, which can draw up to 120W. The loads can run at 12-24V ± 10%.

The solution I'm considering is adding a battery or supercapacitor in the circuit. (This is similar to
[this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525768/limiting-peak-power-consumption-with-energy-bank) but with a higher power disparity.)

- Would a supercapacitor or a battery (likely lead acid) be better suited for this application? I've found ~60F supercap arrays that could easily drive 120W for 10 seconds while only dropping a couple volts, but a battery would be much cheaper.
- Would a diode and power resistor in series be sufficient for limiting the PoE current draw?

  - Is there another relatively simple solution that would allow faster charging, but still gracefully handle a startup with an uncharged capacitor?

[image: suggested circuit]

Comment: The latest PoE standard can support much higher power (up to almost 100 W, IIRC).

Comment: @Null Interesting. However, I'm limited by our existing PoE switches & cabling in this case.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my cameras. For one I purchased an adaptor that supplied the POE rather then the switch. It was not that expensive and is working great.  You could possibly purchase a POE switch and parallel the power connections to get what you need. I am not sure if this would work as I do not know your setup.

Comment: We need to know more about the loads. How will they react to voltage drops, etc.

Comment: @Drew The loads can handle a volt or two of drop. They're specced for 12-24V, though.

Comment: That's not enough info. If they are resistive for example, they will gracefully draw less power as the voltage decreases, so a current limiting resistor could work. But if they're are SMPS's they will try to draw more current to compensate for the drop, and as such, a resistor would simply cause a cascading failure.

Comment: @Drew They're black boxes from our point of view. Likely might have a SMPS inside, but most of the power goes to driving motors and/or solenoids.

Comment: PoE Type 1 has 15W maximum delivered at the Power Sourcing Equipment, but 12.95 W available at the Powered Device.  Also, it has a 37V - 57V range at the powered device.  What are you using to get 12V?

Comment: @Theodore We're using a PoE splitter and a buck converter

Comment: @PurkkaKoodari You need to describe the splitter and how it behaves when it's overloaded.

Comment: @Theodore I'm not sure, but I would assume that it doesn't handle overload gracefully - might as well be behind a fuse.

Comment: Without knowing how the loads will behave, there's nothing you can really do besides shutdown the output if the current exceeds a preset limit. You would then periodically try to restart. There are IC's designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @Drew I know that the average load will be way, way less than 12W over long periods of time. So some kind of battery-based method will definitely work, it's just a case of how complex it needs to be.